# How to call the external library projects in my Android Applications

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-library

```
import com.example.testQRCode.*;  //<--external project 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // create a new intent based on your library activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, QRCode.class); // QRCode is a class from the external projects
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);  
    }
```

The exception displays that the system is unable to instantiate the activity.

Please help me.

Comment: serach on google how to import external project in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to include a library that is an Android Library project in Eclipse, you can simply add it via

`Project Properties->Android`

In this screen, you will see two sections "Project Build Target" and "Library".  In the "Library" section you can add the reference to the other project.

If you mean to include an external jar file, you would do that through the

`Project Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries tab`

In here, there is a button for "Add External Jars..." which you can include the jars you need.

Comment: As someone else has mentioned, can you edit the question and post the full exception log.  It also might be useful to post the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You also have to declare the Activity class of QRCode.class in your main project's AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Then please post the stack trace of the exception.